# How to assign css style to gridview row on ImageButton click?

Tags: c#, css, .net

I'm trying to assign a css class to gridview row, but it does nothing. Code:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)button.NamingContainer;
gvr.Attributes["class"] = "animated fadeOutRight";
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged it, is the event triggered at all?

Comment: yes, event is triggering

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML, if the css is applied to the row?

Comment: yes i have, css is not applied

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "animated fadeOutRight";
        }
    }
```

Css must be applied in RowDataBound only

Comment: Well, he want to change css in the button-click event and only for this row

Comment: I need it to fade out after i press delete